# Processing Query Results in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to execute a query in SQL Server and then print a message that contains data from the query results.

For example, if I had a query like this:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM Customers
```

I'd like to follow it with something like this, for each row of the results.

```
Print N'Customer ID: ' + [ID]
Print N'First Name: ' + [FirstName]
Print N'Last Name: ' + [LastName]
```

I know I can use the `AS` clause to format each column, but the data will always be formatted in a table. Is there any way to format the results differently without using another language to process the results?

Comment: You can take it as XML.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  PRINT output is difficult for client applications to consume and slow besides.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I've been developing software for 26 years and have a pretty good grasp of how hard it is to parse text output. In this case, I will simply copy the output and paste it in an email. I'm clear on what I need. However, most of my expertise is not in SQL Server. I can easily whip up something in C#, but it would be super handy if SQL Server was capable of handling this somewhat trivial task in a simple query.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the parsing, I was referring to the interfacing: PRINT output comes back over a completely different channel from the SELECT data returns.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood - Can you not just copy the entire table of results from SSMS?

Comment: @Paddy: Yes, I certainly can. It's just that it's in the wrong format. It's tabular, which won't be preserved when I paste it in an email. And it really isn't formatted the way I need it. Yes, I really do need it in a different format.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I'm sorry but it's hard for me to get where you are coming from. If I'm simply copying and pasting the data from SSMS to an email, how could any of that possibly matter?

Comment: @JonathanWood Well this is the first that you've mentioned SSMS here, but even so, if you use PRINT you can't use it any other way or with anything else: it has no reusability.  I have posted an example that shows how to do the same thing with SELECT, and avoids having to rely on cursors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a cursor:

```
declare @curse cursor
set @curse = cursor fast_forward for
select ID, FirstName, LastName
from Customers

declare @id int,
        @firstName varchar(32),
        @lastName varchar(32)

open @curse

fetch next from @curse into @id, @firstName, @lastName

while (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
    Print N'Customer ID: ' + @id
    Print N'First Name: ' + @firstName
    Print N'Last Name: ' + @lastName

    fetch next from @curse into @id, @firstName, @lastName
end

close @curse
```

Or you could do it without:

```
select 'Customer ID: ' + cast(ID as varchar(32)) + char(13) + char(10) + 
       'First Name: ' + FirstName + char(13) + char(10) + 
       'Last Name: ' + LastName + char(13) + char(10)
from Customers
```

Use `Ctrl + T` to change your output in SSMS from Grid to Text mode if you use this second way.

Comment: Interesting. Not very familiar with cursors but that appears to be just what I need.

Comment: @muhmud Just a note I had to smile on `@curse`because this really can be a curse :)

Comment: Very true :) Hence, I have added a cursor-less way as well.

Comment: haha! yes! from now on every piece of sample cursor code I generate will use the variable `@curse`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @customerid varchar(100);
DECLARE @firstname varchar(100);
DECLARE @@lastname varchar(100);

SELECT @customerid=ID, @firstname=FirstName, @lastname=LastName 
FROM Customers

Print N'Customer ID: ' + @customerid
Print N'First Name: ' +  @firstname
Print N'Last Name: ' + @lastname
```

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct that, in the case of a query returning multiple results, only the last result would be printed?

Comment: Yes in this case,only the last one as the var get overwrited.

Comment: If you need to do it on multiple rows you need a cursor and do this for each row

Comment: @JonathanWood BTW, if you need data formatted and you do this more often, why don't you just create a simple report using MS SQL Reporting services?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a vertical formatting of the data, then I would still recommend using SELECT over PRINT:

```
SELECT Lbl, Txt
FROM (
              SELECT ID, 'Customer ID:' As Lbl, CAST(ID As VARCHAR(50)) As Txt       FROM Customers
    UNION ALL SELECT ID, 'First Name:' As Lbl, CAST(FirstName As VARCHAR(50)) As Txt FROM Customers
    UNION ALL SELECT ID, 'Last Name:' As Lbl, CAST(FirstName As VARCHAR(50)) As Txt  FROM Customers
    ) A
ORDER BY ID, Lbl
```